# How do you prevent Microsoft Edge from automatically logging in to Microsoft Account?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account, microsoft-edge

(As also asked in this unanswered [forum post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/disable-edge-automatic-login-on-outlook/192c059a-a055-4f16-88fd-197b7e6bf05e))

**Problem**

1. You are logged into a Windows 10 system using your Microsoft
   Account
2. Opening the Edge browser creates a Microsoft Account session for you automatically

**Implications**

- Just navigating to outlook.com can get you access to Mail, Calender etc. of the account!
- Giving the e-mail id to Skype auto logs you in and now you can make calls!

Is there a way to disable this "feature" via a setting in the Edge browser, or worst case, a registry toggle ?

Comment: Have you considered disabling the Edge "Sync your content" feature.  I believe that's the only thing that Edge uses the Microsoft Account for.

Comment: Are you logging into Windows using your Microsoft account, or with a local account?  (yes, I know this is an old question ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I use Edge in private mode (InPrivate Window). Open up from the taskbar directly (right click) or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Edge will not use any local or saved credentials when in private mode. On the other hand, it will not save anything you do (cookies, data storage, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but there is another solution :

Create a Windows 10 local user that does not rely on a Microsoft account.  The process has changed since the start of Win10, and it's different between initial setup of generic Win10 install and from an established install.

In Win10v1809 generic install, when prompted, create a user with sign-in information or Microsoft account.  I don't have a test PC on hand to get the precise steps.  The first user is always an administrator.

In Win10v1809 on an established install, open Settings->Accounts->Other people->Add someone else to this PC.  In the Microsoft Account window, click "I don't have this person's sign-in information", then "Add a user without a Microsoft account".  Enter the local user's name, password, and Security Questions.  Click Next and Change Account Type.  Change the account type to Administrator if you want to be able to install programs, which you probably do.  Sign out of Windows and sign into the new user.  It will take a few minutes, then you can log in, with less Microsoft involvement.

You will need to copy over files and recreate your preferences in applications.

Answer (score -1):

I tried lots of solutions.
Only the following one actually worked :

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Microsoft-Edge-opens-upon-start-up-every-time-and-Chrome-is/td-p/6286239

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken. Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the default windows-spotlight background in the lockscreen. If you click on one of the words in the lockscreen, edge will search for this word after you unlock the screen. So changing the background in the lockscreen worked for me. 
Open settings and search for ‘Change the picture on your lock screen’

Answer (score -2):

There is, at least, a different way. Block the MS server for MS accounts in your hosts file. This will generally block MS accounts. In case you want to use them elsewhere, create a firewall rule for Edge. If it would still work to log in automatically, it'd at least prove that MS software circumvents firewall rules.

Comment: If your suggestion is implemented the user wouldn't be able to log into their computer with their Microsoft Account.

Answer (score -5):

1. Open up an Edge session.
2. Near the top right, there is ... displayed. Click on the ...
3. This brings up a new window.
4. Select settings from the list.
5. Change the second entry to "Open with" to a new tab page.
6. Change the "Open new tab" value to be a blank page.
7. Open up a new Edge session and see if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.